# Cannot implicitly convert type system.Data.EnumerableRowCollectio to System.collection.Generic.Ienumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

this is my code

```
public IEnumerable<TestUser> Getdata()
{
        //return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    TestUserBl tstusr = new TestUserBl();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = tstusr.TestUserSel();
    return dt.AsEnumerable();
}
```

getting error

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: What do `TestUserSel()` method do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `DataTable.AsEnumerable()` gives you `EnumerableRowCollection` as the error message stated, if you need to get the specific object collection you have to get that object like the following:

```
public IEnumerable<TestUser> Getdata()
{
    // Code here
    return dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new TestUser{
                              someId = x.Field<string>("id"),
                             // like wise initialize properties here
                             });
}
```

Comment: i just dont pass any values in function.so what is the use of this  someId = x.Field<string>("id"),

Comment: @AkhilGeorge: That would be the column names of the DataTable, `dt`. you have to map/assign each columns to corresponding properties of the class'

Comment: this gives me <ArrayOfTestUser xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/StarAgentWebApi.Models">
<TestUser>
<tu_cntno i:nil="true"/>
<tu_id>1</tu_id>
<tu_name>Akhil</tu_name>
<tu_pwd i:nil="true"/>
<tu_usrname i:nil="true"/>
</TestUser>
</ArrayOfTestUser>

Comment: how to convert this file type to json